# Boss buys everyone on the Team Lunch

Tags: manager, unprofessional-behavior, lunch

My Boss regularly buys BBQ lunch for the entire team. Today he bought everyone lunch except me. I assumed he had just forgot since our team has ten people which is pretty sizable. When I asked he said that he was only buying lunch for the Testers but then ended up buying it for all the other the devs. I am also a dev.

His excuse was that he only got it for the testers but then also gave food to all the other devs except me. I've seen him do similar things other people right before they quit, get fired, or asked for a raise. He once moved a dev across the office and loudly said it was because he needed to be reminded he was the least useful person on the team.

Is he sending me a message here? Or am I being paranoid?

Comment: Is this the only time it has happened, or is it a recurring thing? He said that he got it for the testers and the devs - what are you?

Comment: Sorry. I should be clear. I am also a dev. His excuse was that he only got it for the testers but then also gave food to all the other devs except me.

I've seen him do similar things other people right before they quit, get fired, or asked for a raise. He once moved a dev across the office and loudly said it was because he needed to be reminded he was the least useful person on the team @DavidK

Comment: Sounds like a pretty poor excuse for a leader to me. Are you being paranoid? We can't know, because we're not him (and thus i'm voting to close this question). However, based on what you've told us, he does seem like the kind of vindictive person who would resort to these sort of "hints". Are you really that distressed about possibly leaving that company?

Comment: @andrei maybe it's really good bbq! man now I'm hungry

Comment: Regularly? Then wait and see if he does the same to you again.

Comment: This sounds like a quiz question from our annual discrimination training.  If it is an isolated occurrence, it might just be a mistake.  If it is a pattern of behavior, it might be discrimination.

Comment: @Lumberjack Thats what I was kinda wondering.

Answer (score 7):

We can't tell if you're paranoid or not. Think about recent interactions with him. Has it changed?  How has your work been perceived as far as you know? Have there been recent layoffs or rumors of layoffs?

About the only thing you can do is ask him directly.  Just flat out ask.  Go into his office or a conference room with him and say, "I don't know if I'm being paranoid or not, but do I have anything to worry about as far as my job goes? I ask because I was **literally** the only dev who didn't get that. Have I done something wrong?"

The only other thing you can really do is wait and see. Regardless, it's a good idea to have your resume up to date anyway, so I'd make sure it's polished and ready to go if you suddenly need it.